# Labeling regressions iterated across columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, label, regression

I'm a beginner in Python and I was wondering if someone can lead me to a thread (if this has been answered before), on the code to label regressions executed over different columns in a dataframe. Currently I am using the following code:

```
def capm_ols(j):
    capm = ols(formula = 'xcesret[column] ~ prem', data=df).fit()
    print (capm.summary())

for column in xcesret:
    capm_ols(j)
```

So the result of this one is I get all my regressions. However, the label of the dependent variable becomes `xcesret[column]` for each of the old tables. This basically renders the analysis useless as I have no way of knowing which dependent variable has been regressed in each result.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
def capm_ols(column):
    capm = ols(formula = column + " ~ prem", data=df).fit()
    print capm.summary()

for column in xcesret:
    capm_ols(j)
```